# How to extract only substring contains kg, g, lb values from the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

#input
df = {fruits : ['Apple 12kg Fresh', '13g Orange, 'Fresh berries 1g, 'strawberry', 'kiwi 3.2lb'   ]}

#desire output:
fruits
12kg
13g
1g
nan
3.2lb

Answer (score 0):

You can use str.extract like this:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({"fruits": ['Apple 12kg Fresh', '13g Orange', 'Fresh berries 1g', 'strawberry', 'kiwi 3.2lb']})
(df.fruits.str.extract(r"(\d+\.?\d*\s*(?:kg|g|lb))", expand=False)
 .rename("fruits"))
```

```
0     12kg
1      13g
2       1g
3      NaN
4    3.2lb
Name: fruits, dtype: object
```

Thanks to the R answer that wrote the first version of this regex before me.

If you need the numbers and units, use two separate capture groups to get the number and unit in separate columns, where you can convert to a numeric column type.